# php / jquery autocomplete from mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

After referencing many previous questions and answers on this topic, I am still stumped. I am attempting to reference the database that stores a user's contact list. As an initial start, I'm keeping things simple and only allowing reference by email (rather than email, first and last names, etc).

I have the following linked:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".emaillist" ).autocomplete({
        source: "contacts.php"}); });
</script>
```

contacts.php: **[UPDATED]**

```
<?php
session_start();
include "scripts/sqlconnect.php";
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$csql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE id='$id' AND email LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term'])."%'");
$contactlist = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($csql)){
    $contactlist[] = $row['email'];
}
$contactlist = json_encode($contactlist);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo "$contactlist";
?>
```

And finally the relevant HTML snippet:

```
<input name="semail" type="text" class="emaillist" id="semail"/>
```

Any suggestions on what I've done wrong? I can't seem to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things that I notice:

1. You never output the contents of `$contactlist`
2. You aren't setting the appropriate `Content-Type` header.

So you want to do this:

```
$contactlist = json_encode($contactlist);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $contactlist;
```

According to [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), the value passed to the AJAX source is called `term`, so you should be using that in your query, not `semail`:

```
...  AND email LIKE "%'. mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) .'%"');
                                                         ^^^^-- Here
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't have an `echo`! Unfortunately, I'm still not getting any autocomplete options when i type in the input field shown above. I do have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in my header of the page, should this be the problem?

Comment: In `contacts.php`?  If you navigate to `contacts.php` directly, what is the output?

Comment: Well you need to pass in the appropriate variables, too: `contacts.php?semail=zeshin`

Comment: are you saying that the `source: "contacts.php"` should instead be `source: "contacts.php?semail=<? echo $_GET['term'];?>"` ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the jQuery UI infrastructure will pass a variable called `term` to `contacts.php`.  Nothing needs to change in your Javascript code.  Just in your backend PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I mean in reference to your previous comment, I'm not sure how that is relevant. I've updated the $_GET in contacts.php and I'm still running dry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16797/discussion-between-sean-bright-and-zeshin)